# BIRT Multi Sorting Functionality

Tags: sorting, birt

Hi I  have a Birt table in which Sort By Group is set to false.
In that table I have multiple column. In sorting script I am sorting the table based on multiple columns.

for example: 
1) sort by column A
2) Sort by column B
3) Sort by Column C

Birt is First Sorts based on A, Then ( A + B) then (A + B + C).

I am confused whether it is right approach. Is this an efficient approach considering sorting is an expensive operation.

Should I create a column binding having (A + B + C) and sort the table once or should I use the Birt's multisort functionality?

Also A, B , C can have different datatype.

for example A = String, B = Integer , C = String null allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no data or performance problems, I would let BIRT do the thinking.

I had a case myself where sorting even required some logic, so I added a column in to the dataset and filled it in the fetch script (using some scripting). I made somekind of string that would result in the correct grouping and sorting. That way the data was only looped once. Sorting was then very easy since it only was one column. Displaying that column also helped debugging the whole thing.